# Java Eclipse JDBC Oracle: DriverManager.getConnection stuck

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, oracle, jdbc

while I'm able to connect and query an oracle database using Oracle SQLDeveloper, I'n not able to do the same from a test java application:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            //Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521/mysid"; //SID
            //String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:myservice"; //service
            String usr = "myuser";
            String pwd = "mypassword";

            System.out.print("Before DriverManager...");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr, pwd);
            if (con == null)
            {
                System.out.print("Connection is null");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Connection OK");
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM mytable");
                while(rs.next()) {
                    System.out.print(rs.getInt(1));
                    //System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Some system details:

**OS**: Mac OS X 10.9.4
**Java Version**: 1.7
**Eclipse**: Kepler (64bit)
**Oracle Client**: instantclient_10_2

After some unsuccessful tentatives, I decided to copy exactly the same JDBC driver used by SQLDeveloper (using show package content). I've copied it under my project folder/lib. And then I added the jar to the build path.

When I run the application on my mac it just remain stuck after printing "Before DriverManager..."

If I run the same application on a colleague windows machine it works fine and print the count results.

I'm really out of options, and I'm starting to think there's some issue with my machine java permission. Is it possible? Any idea where I should look for?

Any help is appreciated.

Regards
Stefano

Comment: Does it throw any exception? Also, uncomment your `//Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");` LoC

Comment: No, it doesn't throw any exception. The above line don't change the application behavior. With or without it, it runs ok on my colleague machine while it hangs on mine.

Comment: I've tested the same code on a Vmware windows 7 (virtual machine) on my mac. And it works. So far, I'm only unable to run it on my mac...

Comment: This can have various reasons. Are you sure you can ping the database machine on your Mac without any issues from your OS?

Comment: On Mac (no vm) I can ping the database without any problem. And that makes sense, because I was already able to connect with SQLDeveloper. I tried right now to run the whole thing on mac with a fresh eclipse installation (LUNA). Same problem...

Comment: Did a test with Netbeans too. Same issue. Definitely related to java installation and not to the IDE.